# Zipcode field validation rule

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created zipcode field in event request tab(custom VF page).
How can i get zipcode number field value like 60616? currently i am getting output like 60,616.

Is there any way like i can write validation rule on this field?

MY valaidation rule is as below

```
AND(
OR(State__c = "IL"),
NOT(REGEX(Zip__C, "\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?")))
```

Comment: Just to make this absolutely clear, `Zip__c` is currently a `number` field, correct?

Comment: This question really has to do with RegEx... regexr.com is a great site that lets you test expressions and tells you more about what the components mean. That being said, why don't you clarify for us exactly what you want the rule to filter for - I assume you're not just looking to check that the input is all numbers?

Comment: @DerekF yes it is number field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have `Zip__c` as a `Number` field. The number field has inherent formatting associated with it, which you're seeing as the comma as the digit grouping separator. This would possibly change with locale (South America, Europe, parts of Africa, and most of Southeast Asia use a full stop `.` as the digit grouping separator, and comma for the decimal separator)

`Number` really isn't the proper field type to use to store postal codes. `Text` is much more appropriate (especially if you're dealing with postal codes from multiple countries, whose postal codes may include more than just digits).

On top of that, the validation rule that you've provided should give you an error when you try to save it because the `REGEX()` function available in validation formulae, to the best of my knowledge, only works on text fields.